# Cumulative count at group level with boolean indexing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm developing an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932614/cumulative-count-at-a-group-level-python) question that just uses boolean indexing rather than `cumcount`. The intended output is a column `total_paid_invoices` that — for each company — counts the number of reach voices paid prior (prior in terms of datetime) to each record.

```
    company invoice date
0   A   1234    20120201
1   A   1134    20120201
2   A   1011    20120201
3   A   1123    20121004
4   A   1111    20121004
5   A   1224    20121105
6   B   1156    20120403
7   B   2345    20120504
8   B   4567    20120504
9   B   8796    20120606
```

I'm handling the company groups in a for loop instead of in a groupby:

```
for company in df.company.unique():
    df['total_paid_invoices'] = df.date.apply(
        lambda x: df.loc[(df.date<x)&(df.company==company)].shape[0]
    )
```

However, the output is incorrect on line five (the value should be `5`):

```
    company invoice date    total_paid_invoices
0   A   1234    2012-02-01  0
1   A   1134    2012-02-01  0
2   A   1011    2012-02-01  0
3   A   1123    2012-10-04  4
4   A   1111    2012-10-04  4
5   A   1224    2012-11-05  4
```

Here's why I'm asking this question: When I do the operation just on the date at line five

```
df.loc[(df.date<df.date.iloc[5])&(df.company=='A')].shape[0]
```

the output is `5`. Why is this not making it into the output dataframe while the rest of the values we see in the sample data are being processed correctly?

Comment: You are overwriting the whole column `total_paid_invoices` in your for loop. Maybe you assigned 5 to that position at some point, but in a future loop you overwrote it with 4. Notice that `unique()` guarantees no ordering in its returned values.

Comment: If you do a `print (df.loc[(df.date<x)&(df.company==company)].shape[0])`, you will find that the values are getting overwritten for `company == 'B'`. Like @rafaelc said, you need to look at an alternate way to address this. I would strongly advice you NOT to use loops. There are so many alternate ways to get this done. Just do a df.apply with groupby and it will solve the problem

Comment: I tried several ways of doing it with df.apply and groupby but just got errors. I’m happy to edit in all the things that didn’t work, or if that’s unnecessary, the solution could just be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rafaelc for pointing out the overwriting issue. You need to index for `company` on both sides of `=` to apply the lambda function to subsets of the dataframe at a time:

```
for company in df.company.unique():
    df.loc[df.company==company, 'total_paid_invoices'] = df.date.apply(
        lambda x: df.loc[(df.date<x)&(df.company==company)].shape[0]
    )
```